# What does the phrase "go for the pin" mean here?

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence from a golf app's description:

> You may be find going for the pin tempting, but sometimes it’s best to
>   take the slow route.

My Google search led me to one meaning (wrestle) of the said phrase. However, I am not sure if it fits the context here.

Comment: The very first hit I got on the Google search "golf pin" was [What Is the 'Pin' in Golf?](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-pin-in-golf-1560950): "Another name for the flagstick, the term pin is used in golf to refer to the pole and oftentimes red flag that courses use to mark each hole on the course. The pins are removed when the golfer gets closer to the hole, or if the ball is flying directly for a hole-in-one from the tee grounds."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the context of golf, the "pin" is the flag that marks the hole. Going for the pin is aiming to get your ball onto the green and next to the pin in one hit.

It sometimes may be better to take two or three hits to get your ball onto the green (because you are more likely for your ball not to roll off the green. You are less likely to hit a bunker). It may be better not to go for the pin, but to take the slow route